# Hashset getting empty string as an element in java

Tags: java, hashset

I am trying to add elements to hashset, but it gets an empty element into it.

Initially I tried,

```
import java.util.*;

public class SetTrial{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
        for(int j=0; j<number;j++)
        {
            String text = sc.nextLine();
            names.add(text);
        }
        System.out.println(names);
    }
}
```

When I give input as,

```
5
a
b
c
d
e
```

It seems to only accept input till `d` and execute print displaying

```
[, a, b, c, d]
```

My guess was that it is accepting a newline at beginning, so I added a `sc.next()` in the code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SetTrial{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
        sc.next();
        for(int j=0; j<number;j++)
        {
            String text = sc.nextLine();
            names.add(text);
        }
        System.out.println(names);
    }
}
```

Although this time it seems to accept all of the input properly, the result is

```
[, b, c, d, e]
```

So the problem must be something else. How do I fix this?

Comment: The next method consumes up to whitespace (carriage return), but not the line feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second approach was nearly right.
Just replace  `sc.next()` with `sc.nextLine()`.